# Mysql database not showing up localhost phpmyadmin (sequel pro)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm doing some local wordpress development, I run everything directly from my machine (don't use MAMP or XAMPP). I'm at the place where I'm ready to take the site live - searching the internet it seems like the best way to extract the database is to use phpmyadmin. Locally, I use sequel pro to create and manage my databases. I just added phpmyadmin to my localhost and can see 2 of my databases, but not all. Does anyone know why that is? I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do (and I'm happy to hear them too) but also curious why some databases are showing up in phpmyadmin while others are not.

thanks :)

Comment: To migrate your WordPress instance live, I suggest you the following plugin: [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/). Very easy to use, it simplify the process of rewriting every URLs depending on the new domain.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that the user connecting through phpmyadmin just simply doesn't have the privileges to see the databases. I'm pretty sure (not 100%) that your path to 'go-live' is dump and restore from local to production and this can be achieved using mysqldump to create your backup file to permit you to copy all the local data into your live machine and restore it. I would assume that sequel pro also permits this activity through gui. If you want to do it like the DBAs do, lookup mysqldump in the MySQL documentation and work from the MySQL command line client. Good luck.